# How does jOOQ support MySQL's dual?

Tags: mysql, jooq

I can't use the [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) generator to generate a `Dual.java` class for MySQL,
but inverse in PostgreSQL

I have included "dual" in the code generation config file:

```xml
<includes>dual</includes>

<name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>
```

I'm using jOOQ's latest version: 2.4.0. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jOOQ, you don't have to worry about the `DUAL` table. jOOQ handles that for you. The following jOOQ query:

```java
create.select(val(1), val(2)).fetch();
```

Will render

```sql
-- MySQL
SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL

-- Postgres
SELECT 1, 2
```

For more info about the `DUAL` tables and similar constructs in various SQL dialects, read this blog post:

http://blog.jooq.org/2011/10/16/sql-trouble-with-dummy-tables/